# Page getting reloaded after doing any post request for angular smart table

Tags: angular6, ng2-smart-table

For angular smart table, I am doing crud operation through http request. But after every http call, page/browser is getting reloaded.

```
deleteBook(id: number) {
return this.http.delete(this.baseUrlBooklist + "/" + id);}

onDeleteConfirm(event) {
    const deletedBook = event.data;
    this.bookService.deleteBook(deletedBook.id).subscribe(
      item => {
        console.log(item);
        event.confirm.resolve(event.source.data);
      }
    );
  }
```

Settings:

```
 delete: {
      confirmDelete: true
    },
```

Html:

```
<ng2-smart-table
[settings]="settings"
[source]="items"
(createConfirm)="onCreateConfirm($event)"
(deleteConfirm)="onDeleteConfirm($event)"
(editConfirm)="onEditConfirm($event)"></ng2-smart-table>
```

For all http request, page getting reload. If removing custom event and not doing http call, then its working without page reload.

Please help me on this regard.

Comment: post your html file of the same

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, This is working fine for me.

```
item => {
        console.log(item);
        event.confirm.resolve();
      }
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. But it seems to be not working.